# How to fix browse-url-firefox for firefox 36.0 in linux?

Tags: linux, web-browser

Firefox 36.0 doesn't have `-remote` option, which is used in the function `browse-url-firefox` for `system-type` gnu/linux by default. How to conveniently bypass this issue?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/q/590265/196895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current [emacs-24](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/log/?h=emacs-24) development branch of Emacs was just updated with the [corresponding change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-24&id=1b0ebbdb566a8dfa5f45ce121b2c835e9760091f).

You can clone and build from it, try applying the same change to your local installation, or wait for Emacs 24.5 to come out, which shouldn't take long now.